# bigquery.tabledata().insertAll method (Bigquery Java API) inserting only partial rows

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am using bigquery.tabledata().insertAll method in Java (Bigquery API) to insert data into BigQuery, but it writes only partial  rows in the table and does not give any error. Where are rest of the rows going?

Comment: What do you mean by "partial"? Some more details would help. Can you share your code, and some examples?

Comment: Please make sure you followed the following troubleshooting guideline, especially check "insertErrors property" and make sure schema is matching.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#streaming

Comment: @polleyg : Partial means- Suppose, I have 12000 rows to be loaded in a Bigquery table, but the code loads less than 12000 rows, it does not give any error.

Comment: If you did what I suggested in the above comment, and it is still like this, then please post your project name, table name, rough time for the call. Then we could do some more investigation.

Comment: I need to do the same and cannot seem to find any example I can use. Would you please share your code on how to call the insertAll method? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It means that if in a loop of 124 rows i insert each one sepreatly they all go in, but if i put them in a batch then only about 8 go in